# Maximal subset with finite Assouad-Nagata dimension

Tags: metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis, geometric-group-theory

Given some space $X$ with non-finite Assouad-Nagata dimension. Is it possible for a subset $Y \subset X$ with finite Assouad-Nagata dimension to exist such that $Y$ is maximal in the sense that if any other point $x_0$ in $X$ would be added to $Y$ then the Assouad-Nagata dimension of $X \cup \{x_0\}$ would become infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Assouad-Nagata dimension is [stable under finite union](http://plaza.ufl.edu/thanos/Text%20Files/asnag4-1.pdf), meaning that $\dim_{AN} (X\cup Y) = \max\{\dim_{AN}X, \dim_{AN}Y)$. Since a point has AN-dimension $0$, adding it to any set does not increase its AN-dimension.